# object doesn't support this property or method whilst trying to click search

Tags: excel, vba

so i am trying to get prices from screwfix website using the code ....

```
Option Explicit

Sub Fetch_From_Screwfix()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet

Dim I As Integer


Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTML_Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim Click As Object

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://www.screwfix.com/"

Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set HTML_Doc = IE.Document


For I = 3 To 3 'sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    HTML_Doc.getElementById("mainSearch-input").Value = sh.Range("A" & I).Value
    HTML_Doc.getElementById("search_submit_button").Click
    
Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Set HTML_Doc = IE.Document

sh.Range("D" & I).Value = HTML_Doc.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
sh.Range("D" & I).Value = HTML_Doc.getElementsByClassName("pr__price").innerText

Next I

End Sub
```

however it comes up with error Object Doesn't Support this property or method, Could someone shed some light on this for me as ive been wracking my brains at this now for a week and cant seem to get it to work, Its litterally the search button which is letting me down on proceeding here.

Thank you in adavanced.

Comment: IE is finally EOL and should no longer be used. It is dead! About your problem: It is not necessary to use the page like a human being. You can simply pass your search term with the URL. For Makita, for example, like this: https://www.screwfix.com/search?search=makita

Comment: So I'm new to coding and trying to get my head around all of it. So for instance how would you get this to run say in edge?

Answer (score 0):

This:
`HTML_Doc.getElementsByClassName("search-btn icon icon-search")(1).Click`

should be
`HTML_Doc.getElementsByClassName("search-btn icon icon-search")(0).Click`

(unless there are >1 elements with that class and you wanted to click the second one)

But probably easier to use:
`HTML_Doc.getElementById("search_submit_button").Click`

Comment: It's strange as I tried both your suggestions before posting on here and it still throws up the same error. Any other ideas? And thank you for your help

Comment: Both of those worked for me - sorry I can't say why they wouldn't for you.  Might be a timing issue - put a break on `Set HTML_Doc = IE.Document` and wait a few seconds before continuing to give the page time to complete any additional rendering.

Comment: Evening Tim appricate the help so far really do! So i got it to work with thanks to you but now getting problem trying to pull the price, using line...

sh.Range("B" & I).Value = HTML_Doc.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    
sh.Range("C" & I).Value = HTML_Doc.getElementsByClassName("pr__prices")(0).innerText

the TagName ("span") is working but the latter one the prices isnt, its for product code 21221 any help would be greatly appricated.

Comment: Please update your post with the additional code and a description of the exact error message you're seeing (and what line it occurs on)

Comment: So i have added the update which is marked between the ** at the beginning and the end thank you for all help and advice

Comment: When you submit the form it's going to load a whole new page, so you need to wait for that process to complete (use the same `IE.ReadyState` loop) and then get a reference to the new page using `Set HTML_Doc = IE.Document` before trying to access any content on the page.

Comment: So i have redone the code above again doing as you stated however its weird i keep getting the error..

Run-Time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method.

I know this is alot to ask but anychance you would be kind enough to have a look for me please and advise on my faults